# prove unique minimal normal subgroup of soluble group by $ P_{G}(M) > M $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $ G $ be a soluble group. If $ P_{G}(M) = \langle y\in G  | \langle y \rangle M = M\langle y \rangle \rangle > M $for any subgroup $ M $ of prime power index in $ G $, then every chief factor of $ G $ has order $ 4 $ or a prime.

For proof let $ G $ be a counterexample of minimal order and choose a minimal normal subgroup $ A $ of $ G $. Hence $ A $ is elementary abelian group of prime power order. since $ G/A $ is a soluble group and $ \vert G/A \vert < \vert G \vert $, so each chief factor of $ G/A $ has order $ 4 $ or a prime. Now i need to prove $ A $ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $ G $. Suppose $ A_{1} $ and $ A_{2} $ are minimal normal subgroups of $ G $ that $ A_{1} \neq A_{2} $. So $ A_{1} \cap A_{2} = 1 $ and each chief factor of $ G/A_{1} $ and $ G/A_{2} $ have order $ 4 $ or prime. Since $ G/A_{1} \times G/A_{2} = G/A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cong  G $, now can say every chief factor of $ G $ has order $ 4 $ or a prime? If it is true, then it is contradiction.

Comment: It is not true that  $G/A_1 \times G/A_2 = G/A_1 \cap A_2$. It is true that $G \cong G/A_1 \cap A_2$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/A_1 \times G/A_2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt How prove $ A $ is unique minimal normal subgroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $H \le G$, and $K/L$ is a chief factor of $G$, then $(H \cap K)/(H \cap L) \cong (H \cap K)L/L$ is a subgroup of $K/L$.

So, if every chief factor of $G$ has order $4$ or prime, then the same is true of any subgroup $H$ of $G$.

So, in your situation, every chief factor of $G/A_1$ and of $G/A_2$ has order $4$ or prime, so the same is true of $G/A_1 \times G/A_2$, and hence the same is true of $G \cong G/A_1 \cap A_2$, which is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/A_1 \times G/A_2$.